# Laravel 5.2 Register while logged

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I need to access the register form while I'm logged, im starting to use laravel 5.2 and guess the Auth not let me being able to register and logged at the same time, how could I do?

Here are my code.

> Routes

```
Route::auth();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

> HomeController

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont do that matey! That is attached to the group middleware "guest" which ANY route governed by that middleware would now be useless. You need to remove the "guest" middleware from that specific route.

Your AuthController should look something like;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{


   use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;


   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->middleware( 'guest', ['except' => [ 'logout', 'register', 'showRegistrationForm' ] ] ); 
   } 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i found how fix it.

> app\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

Comment the if loop `if (Auth::guard($guard)->check())`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    // if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    //     return redirect('/');
    // }

    return $next($request);
}
```